# Azure Resource Manager App Service Networking Route Based

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager, azure-virtual-network

I'm after some advise / help

I've just created an App Service and upgrade the plan to "Standard" to allow access to other resources from within the subscription and resources within our on-premise infrastructure.

When I go to

App Service | Networking | VNet Intergration "Not configured" | Setup

I can see my VNet but its greyed out, when I click on the info button it says the following:

Gateway VPN must be RouteBased

How do I fix this ?

We have a gateway VPN setup as "Site to Site VPN" to our data centre.
Because our Firewall in our data centre only supports "static routing"

So we've setup "User defined routing" UDR

Can any please help

regards

Answer (score 0):

@stravze,
There are multiple reasons that a VNET will be greyed out including:

- the VNET is in another subscription that your account has access to
- List item the VNET does not have Point to Site enabled
- List item the VNET does not have a dynamic routing gateway

Please see this image
[image]

So I recommend you can check your VNet Configuration on Azure.

Comment: We are having the same problem.  We try to connect a App Service to our Policy Based VPN and it says "Gateway VPN must be RouteBased".  Our firewall only supports static VPNs.  How do we get the App Service to work  with the Gateway VPN?